# How to wait until image uploaded to firebase storage in Ionic 2

Tags: firebase, upload, ionic2, loading, wait

I'm trying to wait until image uploaded on firebase storage by using loader but it doesn't work fine

I wrote my code like this but I don't know where is my mistake and why alert show before uploading process.

```
private uploadPhoto(): void {
    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: ""
    })
    loader.present().then(_=>{
        this.myPhotosRef.child(this.generateUUID()).child('myPhoto.JPEG')
        .putString(this.myPhoto, 'base64', { contentType: 'image/JPEG' })
        .then((savedPicture) => {
            this.myPhotoURL = savedPicture.downloadURL;
            this.afd.list('/Images/').push({
                nID: this.appService.id,
                url: this.myPhotoURL,
                date: new Date().toISOString()
            });
        });
    }).then(_=>{
        alert("image uploaded and stored in database");
        loader.dismiss();
    })
}
```

Comment: add a return in the first then `return this.myPhotosRef.child......`

Comment: @mohamadrabee yes, I forgot to write return.. thanks mohamad 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution by adding "return" before "this.myPhotosRef.child..."